# VS Code - Shortcut to quickly switch between debug sessions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, statusbar, shortcut, vscode-debugger

Is there a shortcut in VS Code to switch between (i.e. select) concurrent debug sessions?

I am using StatusBar Debugger and it lacks a button for switching, so I am trying to find a shortcut to do so.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [v1.70 Release Notes: Picker for Debug Seesions](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_70#_picker-for-debug-sessions)

> When debugging, you can now run **Debug: Select Debug Session** in the
> Command Palette. This shows a picker with your active debug sessions,
> which you can use to search and filter your individual debug sessions.
> The description for each picker item will show the session that
> spawned it, if applicable.
>
> Selecting an item in the picker will focus the debug session in the
> Call Stack view. Debug actions (for example, Pause, Step, Restart,
> Stop) will be performed on the focused debug session. Selecting a
> session also shows the session's Debug Console.

And then you can use the standard keybindings for navigating a QuickPick panel.

[image: debug sessions quick pick]